# Moving camera respectively to its location

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut, trigonometry

I thought this will be simple and straightforward, but it is not. I have a camera in openGL application and I am transforming the displayed image respectively to camera "location". Location is changed by <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>. Camera may be rotated using <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd>. When the camera is rotated, the forward and backvard movement should be different. This is what I've made up:

```
  //Somewhere in event handler switch
  else if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP|| key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
    char direction = key==GLUT_KEY_UP?1:-1;   //Whether it is forward or backward movement
    std::cout<<"Moving camera in direction "<<(int)direction<<" with angle "<<rotate_y<<'\n';
    std::cout<<" - this means X is multiplied by "<<((sin((rotate_y/180)*M_PI)+1)/2)<<'\n';
    camera_x += 0.5*((sin((rotate_y/180)*M_PI)+1)/2)*direction;
    camera_z += 0.5*((cos((rotate_y/180)*M_PI)+1)/2)*direction;
  }
```

The original rotation is in degrees, but `sin()` from `math.h` accepts radians. I'm adding 1 to the result to get results between 0-2. Then I change the `sin` or `cos` amplitude from 2 to 1, when I divide the result by 2.
This means - when the camera is looking by 0, 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees, the functions should return 0-1 values. Am I right?
The 0.5 at the beginning is just movement speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want the output of `sin`/`cos` to be in the range 0 - 1.

If you're trying to generate a movement vector in a particular direction, then you need to be generating points in a circle around the origin, which is exactly what you have before applying the scale and offset. Instead you're generating a circle around the point 0.5,0.5, which if used as direction vectors are probably pointing in the wrong direction:

```
Direction  Angle    Vector   Your Vector  Actual Direction
N            0      0,  1    0.5, 1       ~NNE
E           90      1,  0    1  , 0.5     ~ENE
S          180      0, -1    0.5, 0       E
W          270     -1,  0    0  , 0.5     N
```

Notice that you can only generate directions in one quadrant (because your result is always positive) and that none of them are quite what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for making this clear for me. It seems that the OpenGL world is a bit twisted, so I had to do `sin(360-angle)` to get desired result.